# Generic attributes in F#

Tags: c#, f#, c#-to-f#

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 17.7.4 (currently latest) and am trying to get generic attributes to work in F#. I can define them in both C# 11 and F# 7, I can also use/apply them in C#, but it would appear F# doesn't know (yet) what to do with them:

The C# definition:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false]
public class MyCSharpAttribute<T> : Attribute
{
    ...
}
```

And the application in C#

```
public class MyClass
{
    [MyCSharpAttribute<int>]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

The F# definition:

```
[<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)>]
type MyFSharpAttribute<'T>() =
    inherit Attribute ()
    ...
```

And the application in F#

```
type MyType =
    {
        [<MyCSharpAttribute<int>>]
        MyMember1 : string

        [<MyFSharpAttribute<int>>]
        MyMember2 : string
    }
```

Regardless of whether I'm applying the C# or the F# - defined attributes the F# compiler throws 2 errors:

1. FS0010 Unexpected type application in attribute list (this applies to the "<int" bit)
2. FS0033 The type 'My.....Attribute<_> expects 1 type argument(s) but is given 0

It seems the F# compiler is fully aware that there IS a type argument but not how to provide it. I think even in C# 11 generic attributes are still in a somewhat experimental state but maybe there's a trick here I don't know. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think unfortunately for the moment this is unsupported.

I found this language suggestion which is still open: https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/965

Looks like someone tried to come up with an implementation but didn't succeed in landing their PR.

Comment: Thanks @chillitom. I had come across that one as well but I was hoping the F# guys had meanwhile added at least a prototype.